# Task em await Task.WhenAll New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynctask

Estou fazendo um programa `Console`, onde basicamente ele executa esses 4 procedimentos

1. Recupera um `IEnumerable<_Url>`
2. Faz um parsing nessas urls
3. Insere no Database
4. Marca essa _Url, como lida (processada) assim não processa mais

Porém estou recebendo um erro:

> ```
> > New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session.
> ```

**Meu program console está assim:**

```
  private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IEnumerable<Urls> registros = db.UrlsTable.Where(w => w.Lido == false).Take(10);

        ExecutaTarefasAsync(registros).Wait();
    }



public static async Task ExecutaTarefasAsync(IEnumerable<Urls> registros)
        {
            var urlTasks = registros.Select((registro, index) =>
            {
                //parsing html
                var modelProduto = ExtraiDados.ParserHtml(registro.Url);
                db.Produto.Add(modelProduto);

                //save Database
                var downloadTask = db.SaveChangesAsync();


                //marca url como lida
                registro.Lido = true;
                db.Entry(registro).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChangesAsync();

                return downloadTask;
            });

            await Task.WhenAll(urlTasks);
        }
```

Inicialmente estou fazendo com o EntityFramework porque seria a forma mais fácil e depois refatoraria para Dapper ou Ado.Net para máximo desempenho.

Não sei se posso fazer uma 2ª pergunta, mas caso eu faça com Ado.Net eu teria que criar uma função `Parallel.ForEach` para fazer os insert ?

Hoje o problema é que eu faço o download das fotos e essa etapa demora mais do que o parsing, por isso quero utilizar o async corretamente para maximizar o processo, até pq são milhares de registros todos os dias.

Comment: Começo a achar que o problema é um limite do Entity em tentar executar ele dentro do loop, vou tentar enquanto isso fazer uma solução em Ado.Net com Parallel.ForEach

Comment: Você está compartilhando a mesma sessão em mais de uma tarefa... para resolver o problema basta fazer com que o `ExecutaTarefasAsync` possua seu próprio `db`, o criando de tal forma que garanta que o método possua sua própria sessão conectada ao banco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não pode fazer dois acessos `async` em um mesmo contexto ao mesmo tempo:

```
public static async Task ExecutaTarefasAsync(IEnumerable<Urls> registros)
        {
            var urlTasks = registros.Select((registro, index) =>
            {
                //parsing html
                var modelProduto = ExtraiDados.ParserHtml(registro.Url);
                db.Produto.Add(modelProduto);

                //save Database
                var downloadTask = db.SaveChangesAsync();


                //marca url como lida
                registro.Lido = true;
                db.Entry(registro).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChangesAsync(); << ESSE VAI DAR ERRO

                return downloadTask;
            });

            await Task.WhenAll(urlTasks);
        }
```

Crie dois contextos diferentes ou espere um terminar para iniciar outro.

Comment: entendi, e como saberia qual task finalizou para poder executar o update? vou tentar colocar esse 2ª update normal pra ver

Comment: A segunda task do método nem começa, vai dar o mesmo erro com um savechanges normal. Tem que o primeiro `SaveChangesAsync()` terminar para fazer um segundo, mesmo não async

Comment: fiz um teste criando um classe com Dapper apenas para teste e dai funcionou....valeu...era esse problema 2 SaveChanges() não rola.